# jquery ui sortable need to restrict drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery drag and drop

I used the following http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ script for drag and drop

Is need to restrict one particular element only can draggable and others are not.

i.e

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="candrop"></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default candrag"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="candrop"></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

The third `li` has the class `candrag`. So element which has the class `candrag` only be draggable. How to restrict this.

I reviewed the tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_sortable.htm

And it should be drop able in `candrop` class `li`.

But I couldn't get this. Please help me.

Comment: <li> inside <li>...interesting. But why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is explained in the [jQuery UI examples here](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items).

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
  items: "li.candrag"
});

$( "#sortable li" ).disableSelection();
```

But, I think Tejasva is right, you shouldn't drop an li inside an li. Maybe you need to make several sortables and connect them in [connected sortables](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)